# System of ODE with MATLAB, over the unit simplex

Tags: matlab, ode

I would like to get a numerical/qualitative solution for a system of ODE

```
dx_1/dt = f(x_1,x_2,x_3)
dx_2/dt = g(x_1,x_2,x_3)
dx_3/dt = h(x_1,x_2,x_3)
```

where the sum of all variables at any time amounts to 1 (so that the domain is the unit simplex). The functions are a little nasty, and I would just like to have a look at the plot.

I am trying to use MATLAB's solver ode23 or ode45 with the non-negativity constraint turned on, but it doesn't work. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: I would start with ODE45. You can take into account your constrain explicitly, by writing `x3=1-x2-x1`. This, by the way, imposes constraint on your functions `f,g,h`:  `f+g+h=0` at any time. So you have to solve just to ODE's

Comment: This sounds more like a [DAE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/differential-algebraic-equations.html) rather than an ODE. "I am trying to use MATLAB's solver ode23 or ode45 with the non-negativity constraint turned on, but it doesn't work." – it's hard to say if you might be doing something wrong with only this. Show us your code.

Comment: Also note that you can evaluate your functions inside the ODE function in steps. So that common parts can be separated out and only evaluated once, leading to more expressions of a shorter size. This may also lead you to detect that the condition `f+g+h=0` is contained rather explicitly in the final expressions.